# Is this try-catch block valid?

Tags: c#, try-catch

Newby question...

Is it valid to do:

```
try
{
    // code which may fail
}
catch
{
    Console.Writeline("Some message");
}
```

Or do I always have to use:

```
try
{
    // code which may fail
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Writeline("Some message");
}
```

Comment: Get a compiler and compile it. Then see.

Comment: @BoltClock That dosn't help much. That's like testing a function with a single input and deciding that it works for all inputs. Better to read the language spec. Are you proposing that PeeHaa tries all possible ways to raise an exception to see if they are all caught?

Comment: Next question to consider: Is either approach recommended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both blocks are valid.

The first will not have an exception variable.

If you are not going to do anything with the exception variable but still want to catch specific exceptions, you can also do:

```
try 
{
   // your code here
}
catch(SpecificException)
{
   // do something - perhaps you know the exception is benign
}
```

However, for readability I would go with the second option and use the exception variable. One of the worst things to do with exceptions is swallow them silently - at the minimum, log the exception.

Comment: I believe as of .NET 2, all unmanaged exceptions are (by default) converted into managed exceptions anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I trust you are right, but would like to see MS documentation that says so ;)

Comment: OK, found it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.sehexception.aspx

Comment: @Jon - took some digging. Wouldn't expect it to be documented under `SEHException` remarks :(

Answer (score 3):

Yep, absolutely, such a catch block called general catch clause, see more interesting details in the **C# Language Specification 4.0, 8.10 The try statement:**

> A catch clause that specifies neither an exception type nor an
>   exception variable name is called a general catch clause. A try
>   statement can only have one general catch clause, and if one is
>   present it must be the last catch clause

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your first block of code valid. It will catch all exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

It is. It will catch all the exception. So the two code examples do the same.

Answer (score 1):

First one is valid, and it acts just like the second one.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

> The catch clause can be used without arguments, in which case it
>   catches any type of exception, and referred to as the general catch
>   clause. It can also take an object argument derived from
>   System.Exception, in which case it handles a specific exception.

Answer (score 1):

As @David answered this is valid.
You could use second syntax if you want to get more infos or catch a specific exception. 
E.g.

```
catch (Exception e) 
{
  Debug.Print(e.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is valid.

you can always refer to this article:

[Best Practices for Handling Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on MSDN

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is valid, you specify `catch(Exception e)` when you want to output the error message ex.Message, or to catch a custom or a concrete Exception. Use `catch`  in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Writeline("Some message");
}
```

In this block you can use SqlException, etc..

```
catch (SqlException e)
{
    Console.Writeline("Some message");
}
```

For this use the "(SqlException e)"

If you will use a generic menssage, use this:

```
catch
{
    Console.Writeline("Some message");
}

or

catch (Exception)
{
    Console.Writeline("Some message");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that you can chain catch your exceptions. This will allow you to handle different scenarios based upon the exception(s) the code may throw.

```
try
{
    //Your code.
}
catch(SpecificException specificException)
{
    //Handle the SpecificException
}
catch(AnotherSpecificException anotherSpecificException)
{
    //Handle AnotherSpecificException
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
    //Handle any Exception
}
```